# Placeholder/Hoover containing data from Model

Tags: html, razor

I have  view with a list of images and I want to show the title of that image from a placeholder or on hoover.
Is there a way to do that? Perhaps with jquery or JS?

This is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div>@Html.DisplayFor(@model => model.Product)</div>
    if (Model.Images != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Images)
        {
            <img src='@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)' alt="Image" onclick="SendEmail()" id="images" class="imagethesame" placeholder="@Model.Product??" />   }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another work-around for this problem, easier for developers. The data from the controller comes with JSon in a stylish popup from SweetAlert.

```
function GetNames() {
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("GetProductName","Shop")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                swal({
                    title: data + " costs 4$. Click Ok for adding it to your shopping cart! ",
                },

            function () {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "MainPage")';
            })
            }
        });
    }
```

Perhaps is not related to the question, but it is a simple, elegant solution.